What does the binary `^` operator (caret, circumflex, hat) do?
What does (i ^ j) mean in C programming. I trying to study for the exam and this was on the practice test and i have no idea what it means.
I am guessing it has something to do with bit shifting (not a 100% sure though).

Isn't the meaning of all the operators in your teaching material?

It really only needs looking up operator specifications. What makes this tricky in an exam situation is that many people in many contexts (other than programmers reading C code, or "similar languages" if you allow a C person in context of a C question to phrase like that...) think "power of". You really need to get that out of your mind when doing C.

This is known as the XOR operator. It will bitwise xor every bit within the type. If it's an integer, it will do this for 4 bytes, depending on the system.
For example:
int i = 5; // bitwise this looks like ...0101
int j = 6; // this looks like 0110
int answer = j ^ i; // 0011 or 3 in decimal.

Here is a table to understand the xor logic gate
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/xor-gate/

If the operands are not both integer types, the code won't compile (see §6.5.11 The bitwise exclusive OR operator).

I do not get the relevance of "If it's an integer, it will do this for 4 bytes, depending on the system.". How would that be different for 2 bytes and why does that depend on the system?
